# Obtener solamente un dato en consulta sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

tengo una consulta sql server que lista 2 columnas, idtiket y horas sql las cuales provienen de la tabla tiket y ACTIVITY_LOG, la cuestion es que deseo que por cada ticket me liste la ultima hora de la tabla ACTIVITY_LOG y no se repita.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funciona cuando esta solo y con un top1

```
SELECT top 1
T.ID_TICK,RIGHT('0' + CAST(TIEMPO_ACT / 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(TIEMPO_ACT % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST((TIEMPO_ACT % 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
FROM TICKET T    
INNER JOIN Entity..ACTIVITY_LOG AL    
 ON T.COD_TICK = AL.NAM_SUBTYPE_ACT    
WHERE T.ID_TICK = 511375
```

el problema es que  cuando quiero listar más de 1 ticket, me lista solamente el último y yo deseo que me liste los 2 ticket con sus ultima hora y no solamente 1

```
 SELECT top 1
T.ID_TICK,RIGHT('0' + CAST(TIEMPO_ACT / 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(TIEMPO_ACT % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST((TIEMPO_ACT % 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
FROM TICKET T    
INNER JOIN Entity..ACTIVITY_LOG AL    
 ON T.COD_TICK = AL.NAM_SUBTYPE_ACT    
WHERE T.ID_TICK = 511375 or T.ID_TICK = 448276
```

solo acotar que ya probe con distinct y no funciona tampoco

Comment: Agrupa por ticket y usa max(hora).

Comment: no tenes que usar top.. tenes que usar group by ;) (que es lo que te pusieron en el comentario de arriba)

Comment: hola me podrían dar  un ejemplo por favor, ya que no conozco mucho sqlserver, se los agradecería mucho

Answer (score 0):

La consulta original se convierte en una subconsulta para facilitar el agrupamiento posterior. Luego se agrupa por `ID_TICK` y se selecciona la máxima hora de cada grupo:

```
SELECT ID_TICK, MAX(HORA) HORA
FROM (SELECT T.ID_TICK,
             RIGHT('0' + CAST(TIEMPO_ACT / 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(TIEMPO_ACT % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) +
             ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST((TIEMPO_ACT % 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) as HORA
      FROM TICKET T
               INNER JOIN Entity..ACTIVITY_LOG AL
                          ON T.COD_TICK = AL.NAM_SUBTYPE_ACT) as Tabla
WHERE ID_TICK IN (511375, 448276)
GROUP BY ID_TICK
```